# How to deicde max size of HTML() in flutter_html?

Tags: css, flutter, dart, font-size, flutter-html

I'm controlling max size of FontSize by Mediaquery,but only HTML(), it is larger than Text() when Device's Accesibility for TextSize is full.[[this is screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHIZl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJONp.png)

I tried adding FontSize() and FontSize.medium in the Style() but not solved.
I couldn't find but Are there any source code that resizes the FontSize in propotional to ScreenSize or Device setting?